# Geometric interpretation of complex exponentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In complex analysis, function $e^x$ has a pretty simple geometric interpretation. We can use it to define ''exponentiation with different bases'' using $a^b = e^{b \ln a}$. But this turns out to be a little bit uglier than in reals, because complex logarithm has multiple branches (some say it's ''multivalued'') so for some numbers this ''exponentiation with different bases'' can have multiple results.

It seems to me that all other operations on complex numbers have simple geometric interpretation, but this ''exponentiation with different bases'' seems a little bit unnatural. Is there a nice geometric interpretation? I would also be thankful for some examples where this operation is useful (define useful as you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find $a^b$, draw a [logarithmic spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) from $1$ to $a$. Then $b$ tells you how far to go along the spiral to get to $a^b$. (Just make sure that you move at a speed proportional to your distance from $0$.)

- If $0<b<1$, then you stop somewhere between $1$ and $a$.
- If $b>1$, then you continue on the spiral past $a$ towards $\infty$.
- If $b<0$, then set out from $1$ in the opposite direction, spiraling in towards $0$.
- If $b$ isn't a real number, that means that you depart from the curve at the appropriate angle.

This procedure is usually multivalued, because there are many different spirals that pass between two points. (If we're pressed to choose one, we usually prefer the least tightly wound spiral, i.e. the principal value.) It's only when $b$ is an integer that it doesn't matter which one you take!

Comment: Excellent! But why not, in the $b \in \mathbb{R}$ case, instead of being careful about our movement speed on the curve, just consider $\theta =2 \pi b$?

Comment: @AHB That's a useful point! I didn't think of it when I wrote this answer. Just beware that in the special case when the "spiral" degenerates to a straight line, we can't rely on $\theta$.